# AndroidManifest.xml already defines debuggable (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.android, android-manifest

I am trying to build a hello world application and whenever i try to build it i get the error

AndroidManifest.xml already defines debuggable (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest.

For the past 3 hours i have been trying to figure what's wrong but to no avail.

I am using VS2012 with mono for android.

Could somebody at least tell me what is causing this problem.

Comment: couldt understand your question ? can you tell what error are you getting ?

Comment: whenever i try to build i get the following error  AndroidManifest.xml already defines debuggable (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest.

Comment: i am using visual studio 2012 with mono for android

Comment: huh...i don't think its possible to use eclipse with mono for android. Their documentation says either user monodevelop or visual studio and i am getting the same error for both.

Comment: It is a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 2):

This is not actually an error, just a warning. Your app will run fine without changing anything regarding this. You will need to pay it more attention when/if you end up publishing an app, but for now you may safely ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: Set it to Release and rebuild then set it back to Debug and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

VS2012 should enable you to see the actual manifest, and removing the debuggable attribute should solve this.  I do not use VS2012 but for command line you pass the ant target name (in this case 'debug') to the build process, so having android:debuggable="true" in the AndroidManifest.xml is redundant.